# Add manually installed application to 'Show Applications' grid in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I have manually (from command line) installed a software on my Ubuntu 18.04. How do I add it to the "show applications" grid?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do that by creating a launcher for the application (`.desktop` file) in your `~/.local/share/applications` directory.

If you want the application to be available to all users, you can put the `.desktop` file in the `/usr/share/applications` directory.

First create an empty text file, name it something like `<application-name>.desktop`, and add the following lines to it

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Application Name
Comment=A short description of the application
Exec=/full/path/to/application/executable
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/full/path/to/icon-file
```

Then save the file. If it doesn't appear in '*Show Applications*' grid straightaway, log out and login again.

You can do the same by using GUI applications, for example '**Main Menu**' (aka `alacarte`). Install it by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Comment: perhaps it is useful to add that one can add the .desktop file to /usr/share/applications if it needs to be made available for all users.

Comment: @vanadium Please feel free to edit that in.